# Is it "mid-air", "midair" or "mid air"

Tags: hyphens, compounds, orthography

> The bird feels the breeze all around it when it's in mid-air.

Is it "mid-air", "mid air" or "midair"? I have seen all three of them in various context, so I am not sure if all of them are valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most dictionaries list it as ***"midair"*** see: [dictionary.cambridge.org/midair](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/midair)

A few others list it as ***"mid-air"***, see [dictionary.cambridge.org/mid-air](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mid-air)

and none I could find list ***"mid air"***.

So as a **conclusion** I would say *midair* and *mid-air* are both correct, but *mid air* is not.

**edit:** moreover definitions given by the Cambridge Dictionary for both *midair* and *mid-air* are the same:

> noun  /mɪdˈeər/
>   **a point in the air, not on the ground:**
>   *She caught the ball in midair.*
>   *She caught the ball in mid-air.*

Answer (score 0):

Mid air is an expression that is rarely used by people in aviation, as they have more accurate words in their vocabulary. Such as airborne, mid flight,cruise level etc. Mid air has little meaning, mid way between what? It could have come from trapeze artist acts. As in inbetween the thrower and catcher, in mid air.....Wow, gasp, how dangerous is that?

Comment: I guess it is probably easier for learner to understand which expression is your suggestion if you could add some conclusion.